# Non-EU student wants to start working in Germany company right before finishing Master's thesis

Tags: germany, blue-card, students

I am a student in Munich and in the last stage of my thesis. I got a job (in IT) and my contract starts from June (this date has already been pushed from April and hence no further changes can happen). My company wants a work and residence permit for me to start working. Since I will be ending my thesis at that point, is it possible to apply for the EU blue card, given I won't have a Masters degree at hand and yet to submit my thesis? Has anyone faced similar issues before?

Answer (score 1):

Your student residence permit should already contain a work permit allowing you to work 120 full days per year (please double-check it). If you were not working on it already this year, it means you can use it to work full-time approximately for the first 5-6 months. These 5 months should be enough to finish the master, get a degree and apply for another residence permit / work permit.

Considering what your company **wants**, it is really important that you have a contract signed from both sides now. Just answer to the company that you will provide them the work permit on the first working day, as it is supposed to be by law.